# Vetur error with finding tsconfig.json or jsconfig.json

Tags: vue.js, tsconfig

I keep getting an error with making new vue pages for my project. The error is saying:

> Vetur can't find `tsconfig.json` or `jsconfig.json` in /xxxx/xxxxxx.

What would be the solution to fix this problem?

Answer (score 6):

To create the file :)

[See the docs](https://v3.vuejs.org/guide/typescript-support.html#recommended-configuration)

```js
// tsconfig.json
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "esnext",
    "module": "esnext",
    // this enables stricter inference for data properties on `this`
    "strict": true,
    "jsx": "preserve",
    "moduleResolution": "node"
  }
}
```

Comment: Do I add it In the vue folder or in the package.json file?

Comment: @JohnwasHere Add the file to the root of the project, same folder as `package.json` :)

Comment: is it a file by itself added to the folder or a code chunk added to package.json file?

Comment: @JohnwasHere Cerate a new file in your project directory called `tsconfig.json` and paste the content from the answer.

Comment: What about package.json, what should be inside of it?

Comment: I'm unhappy that `vue create` does not provide this file automatically. That being said, I'm not familiar with how they (Vetur and vue-cli) work.